# Java: Fastest structure to store and retrieve large number of strings

Tags: java, list, data-structures, tree

I need to create a **Java** *structure* to store a large number of `String`. Then I basically need to add new strings and also check if some string is already present... The order of the strings is not important.

I don't know many Java datatypes but the typical `List`, `Set` and `Map`, so... what would be the fastest datatype for this scenario? May it be a `TreeSet` or is there any other I'm missing?

Comment: Hashing is usually quite fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on which kind of access you need.

- sequential: `LinkedList<String>`
- random: `ArrayList<String>`
- check for presence: `HashSet<String>` (this is the one you are looking for according to your reqs)
- check for presence and sorted traversal: `TreeSet<String>`

Comment: Thanks @Jack, in fact, I don't need any kind of sorting, so I think I'll go for `HashSet`...

Comment: @MikO: HashSet is good if you have a lot of data. If your amount of data is small, then the cost of calculating the hash function adds some expense, but likely this is what you want.